# Line of Sight AI for Enemies in a Topdown 2D unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently building a 2D topdown zombie survival game in unity where the player must run around an environment trying to get collectibles, I'm looking to have the zombies spawn from different points around the map when the player gets close to a spawn point, but id like for the enemies to only follow/chase the player when they can see them (Compared to what I have now in which they just move to the player straight away). Does anyone have any good links or ways of implementing this? all the  tutorials I have looked at are for a playable character and not an enemy NPC.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) from the NPC to the player to check for a clear line of sight
2. [Create a field of vision](https://answers.unity.com/questions/41759/creating-enemy-field-of-vision.html) to determine the angle of their peripheral vision
3. Ensure any successful raycast is within the angle of vision
4. If all of this is true then trigger the navmesh agent to walk towards the player.

Optionally, you can record the last player position where the NPC spotted the player; then if they break LOS (line of sight) the zombie moves to that position and looks around to re-establish LOS.

Comment: I'd add that you would only want to Raycast if the player is within a certain range. I prefer to use a CircleCollider2D as a trigger and notify the AI if the player enters it to start raycasting for line of sight.
Especially when you are planning on using a lot of zombies, this could improve performance significally.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks for the help ill start looking into using those